# How to measure load for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, load, monitoring

With thread-based concurrency, OS tools can easily measure load.

I am struggling to measure the "load" of my Node.js process. (As in how many things are waiting on processor time.)

The CPU usage of my process near 100%, but I have no idea if that the process is at CPU capacity or multiple times above it.

Comment: You say "near 100%".  If it's at 100% for anything other than a moment, then you're exceeding the single CPU core capacity and a more efficient design or clustering is probably in order.  If you're below 100%, then you still have some headroom.   Before you go to clustering, it would be worth understanding why you're near 100% because perhaps there are some things in the design such as removing any synchronous I/O or moving one or two CPU-sucking tasks to a thread pool or child processes) that could make a huge difference.

Comment: @jfriend00, but 100% CPU at a load of 1.01 and 100% CPU at a load of 10 are very different. The former is unconcerning. The latter means I am 10x underprovisioned.

Comment: Sure, there are degrees of 100%, but if you're averaging 100%, you're overloaded, somewhat by definition. Peak loads will be experiencing delays.  I would think you don't  want that, whether it's 1.1 or 2.0. I would think you want to see the average load significantly below 100% where it's entirely clear that you have at least a bit of headroom for busy times. So, I'm just suggesting that an average load of 100% is a problem you should address, regardless of how far over it is. And, when you get into what is causing it, you may find some low hanging fruit that give you a bunch of new headroom.

Answer (score 0):

use Software "Apache JMeter". this used to measure the load of nodejs to see how to measure you can see this video [How use Apache jmeter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nen32GXVeB4)